# Sentinel API query, rows exceeds maximum number

Tags: python, remote-sensing, sentinel-1, opensearch-api

I am trying to query Sentinel1A data using the Sentinel API, by using the following scripts.

```
from sentinelsat.sentinel import SentinelAPI
api = SentinelAPI('username', 'password',
                          'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/')
api.query(location_str, '20150101', '20150110', producttype='GRD')
```

I am getting the following error

> sentinelsat.sentinel.SentinelAPIError: (HTTP status: 500, code: None) # HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter `rows` exceeds the maximum value (100)

Scihub and API Hub recently updated to limit the number of rows to be returned in a single query to 100, as posted [here](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/news/News00111) might be the reason for this error.

How to make OpenSearch API query to return less than 100 rows ?

Comment: We are working on a new release. In the meantime you can follow [the Pull Request for this](https://github.com/ibamacsr/sentinelsat/pull/60#issuecomment-256869591).

Comment: Thanks @Kersten . I got it working for time being by changing the line number 132 of sentinel.py as in double quotes "return urljoin(self.api_url, 'search?format=json&rows=90')"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Version 0.7.1 of sentinelsat](https://github.com/ibamacsr/sentinelsat/releases/tag/v0.7.1) has just been published to Pypi and solves this issue.

Root cause was the change in behaviour of the `rows` argument in SciHubs OpenSearch protocol. `sentinelsat` now queries 100 results at a time until no new scenes are returned. (see the documentation for further info).

Discussion of the changes can be found in the [related pull request](https://github.com/ibamacsr/sentinelsat/pull/60).

disclaimer: I am a contributor to the sentinelsat project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **$top** parameter in OpenSearch:

**$top :** Determines the maximum number of records to return.

**Example:**

```
https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/odata/v1/Products?$top=50
```

this OData URI allows to list 50 products.

*ATTENTION: $top accepts as maximum value 100. For higher values it will result in an error ( http 500 ).*

**Reference:**
https://scihub.copernicus.eu/userguide/5APIsAndBatchScripting